# Multi Query Support in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

I've searched the web a long time and found no solution. I'm trying to insert in a table, get the ID of the record and insert x times in another table.
My code is

```
$first = true;
$sql  = 'INSERT INTO
`pf_employees` (firstname, surname, `occupationGroup`, birthday, image)
VALUES ("'.$name.'", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)';
$sql .= 'INSERT INTO `pf_roster_employees` (weekID, dayID, employeeID) VALUES ';
foreach($days as $temp) {
    if(!$first)
        $sql .= ', ';
    $sql .= '("'.$weekID.'", "'.$temp.'", last_insert_id())';
    $first = false;
}
$result = $config['database']->query($sql);
```

This results in something like this:
`[...] INSERT INTO pf_roster_employees (weekID, dayID, employeeID) VALUES ("1", "1", last_insert_id()), ("1", "4", last_insert_id()), ("1", "5", last_insert_id())`.

The Interpreter says `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO`pf_roster_employees`(weekID, dayID, employeeID) VALUES ("1", "1", ' at line 1`

Is there any more convenient way to replicate the second query? I mean, SQL is much more faster than PHP, and of course, I feel very ashamed of using this dirty code.

Thank you.

Comment: if you use `mysqli` it supports multi statements. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot `;` here for separating sql queries

```
 NULL, NULL, NULL)';
                 ^

NULL, NULL, NULL);';
```

Also use `mysqli_*` ,it supports to run multiple query in one sigle statement.

Comment: I'm already using `mysqli` (or at least I think so). The db-connection is given with `$config['database'] = @new mysqli(host,user,passw,database);`
EDIT: Thank you! With `multi_query` instead of `query` it works great!

Comment: @MartinWeise Then you forgot that `;` after first insert query.